# Change URLs of DIV

Tags: php, jquery

I have two "DIV" with multiple URLs, but only one should change the basis of this...

```
<div class="1">
<a href="/1.php">AAAA 1</a>
<a href="/2.php">AAAA 2</a>
<a href="/3.php">AAAA 3</a>
<a href="/4.php">AAAA 4</a>
<a href="/5.php">AAAA 5</a>
</div>

<div class="2">
<a href="/10.php">AAAA 10</a>
<a href="/20.php">AAAA 20</a>
<a href="/30.php">AAAA 30</a>
<a href="/40.php">AAAA 40</a>
<a href="/50.php">AAAA 50</a>
</div>
```

Only I have to edit the div "1" .. I want it to be as follows

```
<div class="1">
<a href="http://www.url2.com/1.php">AAAA 1</a>
<a href="http://www.url2.com/2.php">AAAA 2</a>
<a href="http://www.url2.com/3.php">AAAA 3</a>
<a href="http://www.url2.com/4.php">AAAA 4</a>
<a href="http://www.url2.com/5.php">AAAA 5</a>
</div>

<div class="2">
<a href="/10.php">AAAA 10</a>
<a href="/20.php">AAAA 20</a>
<a href="/30.php">AAAA 30</a>
<a href="/40.php">AAAA 40</a>
<a href="/50.php">AAAA 50</a>
</div>
```

The div "2" continues the domain url.

Comment: According to your tag, you are using PHP -- please post the PHP code that generates your HTML.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question and add more details. Do you want to change the URL using jQuery?

Comment: I'd use the SimpleXML for this, http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php, but that is my preference. There are lots of ways to do this, what have you tried? What issues are having? Also depends on if I'm understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: The code is obtained from a source with php .. If you can change with jquery no problem, but not well as used ..
I just need to change the div that, as is the obtrengo another site without modifying the url rest of mine..

Comment: you should change the php that generates the urls

Comment: but the php not generate the urls.. only the obtains of other site

Answer (score 0):

Can use jQuery `attr(fn)` which will loop over each element to change them.

```
var linkDomain = 'http://www.url2.com';

$('div.1 a').attr('href', function(_, existinghref){
    return linkDomain + existinghref;
});
```

Reference: [attr(function) docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)